# how do you eliminate white space from the Dom with hidden unicode characters?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QbyUR/

So, I have an empty TD, that I'm trying to remove the white space from.

Normally I'd do this:

```
ee.replace(/\s+/, '') == "" // check to see if TD is empty.
```

the above returns false

but, it wasn't working so I pasted the contents of my TD to a unicode decoder and got this:

```
U+000D <control> character
U+000A <control> character
U+0009 <control> character
U+0009 <control> character
U+0009 <control> character
U+0009 <control> character
U+0020 SPACE character
```

or

```
&#x000d;&#x000a;&#x0009;&#x0009;&#x0009;&#x0009;&#x0020;
```

The text that I converted is here:

```
-------


-------
```

(in between the two lines)

this is what I used: http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/utf8-decoder

I'm 100% certain it's the control characters that are messing me up. And they are bound to be different across all browsers...

How do I get rid of them? is a regex replace going to be sufficient?

Comment: The answers explain what's really wrong, but note that the "control characters" in question here are just newline, carriage return, tabs and space, all of which will be matched by `\s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem here is that you're using `innerText`, which is not a property on jQuery objects but rather on DOM elements. Simply use the jQuery function `.text()` instead:

```
var e = $(".td");
var result = e.text().replace(/\s+/, '') == ""; // check to see if TD is empty

alert(result);​
```

And everything will work fine. Right now, the string is actually `"undefined"` because you appended an empty string to a nonexistent property.

Comment: @TheLindyHop: No, trust me, it's correct. Have you actually tried it?

Comment: Not yet, Will tomorrow on the computer it was happening on, want to make sure everything is exactly the same. I appreciate your help though! =D
Will def +1 and check if this works.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do will work correctly, but you wrote your Javascript wrong.  Since you're using jQuery to select the element, you need to get the first index to access the `innerText` of the element.

http://jsfiddle.net/QbyUR/5/